# Можно ли добавлять кнопки в клавиатуру из бота?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Делаю "магазинчик" В телеграме, дошёл до стадии создания админки. Возможно ли как-то писать боту параметры для кнопки, и чтобы он добавлял эту самую кнопку? Заранее спасибо

Comment: да, все это описано в апи телеграма. можно и инлайн кнопки добавить и менять клавиатуру добавив в нее кнопки.

Comment: @alex Не нашел ответа на свой вопрос в апи, там просто описан способ их создания и не более. Возможно я упустил момент.